# Magento 2.1.7 to 2.1.15 upgrade issue

Tags: magento-2.1, product, upgrade, composer, home-page

I have upgraded my magento version 2.1.7 to 2.1.15. The upgrade process working fine. But the issue is my home page contents are not loading. It loada product detail page content in the home page.

Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the product URL key has been set as empty in the database. Please check for the empty value in the column "request_path"  of table "url_rewrite". If you found anything, remove that row.

Comment: This worked for me.